# unable to save jupyter notebook on vs code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, save, jupyter

on vs code (last version) I can create a new jupyter notebook typing:
'Jupyter: Create New Jupyter Notebook'

but then I can't save it as I don't have the extension ipynb on the saving window.
If I try with python or json extension it doesn't work
I have python and jupyter modules installed
I have on an other computer vs code (an other  and I don't have this problem
I have uninstall module jupyter and reinstall it (version v2022.2.1030672458) with no sucess

do you know what it could be?

Comment: You are actually right, that might be a bug. For the time being, create a file manually and name it right (ex: my_file.ipynb) and then open it with VS Code.

Comment: An interesting approach, although i have never considered trying this given it is far more convenient (and considerably faster) to click `new file` and name the file (with any language extension) that you want...